# How can I see precisely what files were added and changed by package installation?

Tags: ubuntu, apt

My goal is to install a package, and then tar up ONLY the files that were added or changed by the process of installing that package.

I am using apt-get on ubuntu 16.10

I have tried using overlayroot and this seems to be a good-ish partial solution, but the problem is that the overlay directory contains quite alot of other stuff too, because overlayroot starts when the system is booted so there seems to be various other files that get modified during boot.

Maybe I need to be able to create the root overlay immediately prior to running the package install command.  I have had no luck doing that though - changes to files in the root showed up in the upper directory, but changes made further down the file system did not.

Can anyone please suggest how I can get a list of all files modified by aot-get package installation please?

Comment: Does this help http://askubuntu.com/questions/32507/how-do-i-get-a-list-of-installed-files-from-a-package ?

Comment: Maybe [installwatch](https://asic-linux.com.mx/~izto/checkinstall/installwatch.html) will help.